# Gulp output to multiple files rather than one big file?

Tags: javascript, build, gulp, frontend, browserify

Is it possible to configure the gulpfile to output several files rather than one?
All the examples I came across demonstrate minification and concatenation of all js files into one big bundle js file the index.html would load.
When your apps get bigger and more complex using many libraries, this bundle gets bloated pretty quickly and you come to an understanding that one big bundle file is not a good fit to scale your app.
Is this concatenation a must? or can we simple minify & uglify & browserify each file to a corresponding minified version in the output folder?

Cheers
Ajar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely configure a gulpfile to output several files rather than one. For instance, I have a gulp task:

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
  gulp.src('dev/less/*.less')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(prefix())
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});
```

I have 5 .less files in my less folder, and they become 5 .css files with matching names in my distribution folder.

And for JavaScript files as well:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  gulp.src('dev/landing/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});
```

Four JavaScript files become uglified versions of themselves in my `distribution/js` folder.

However, this is a different question if you want to address `browserify` specifically. `browserify` builds with the intent of including any dependencies stemming from your initially included JavaScript file.

If keeping separate files is more important to you, you can look into [browserify-deoptimizer](https://github.com/domenic/browserify-deoptimizer)